# Control session variable inside MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, bootstrap-modal

I am developing MVC application where people can sign up. After signing up, a page will display confirmation message using bootstrap modal. The **modal** block on the view is checking a session variable first, if the session is not null, then it will be displayed:

```
@if (Session["signUpName"] != null)
{
    <!-- Modal start -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#signUpModal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="signUpModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-    dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Registration Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Dear @Session["signUpName"]</p>
                    <p>Thank you ......</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal end -->
}
```

My issue is after signing up, I can't get rid of the modal window!! I tried to make the session equals to null inside the if statement with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: What I mean when I said (I can't get rid of the modal window!!) is after closing the modal and refresh the page, the modal window will apear again because the session variable is still has data

Comment: Session only exists on the server. Modal only exists on the client. Your modal is only going to check values that were evaluated on the server but do not change on the client. To connect the two, you need an AJAX call from the client to execute an action method on the server, which returns the value from session state.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Session for this. The whole point of MVC is to use Models for your views.
So, create a model class to hold whatever data you need for the view. The moment you start using session and think about clearing it in the view you've gone as far away from MVC as you can get. This isn't webforms or classic asp, you need to think in a different way.

So, you could create your model from Session values. If you need to clear the session, do it in the controller, before you load the view. Keep your view as dumb and as simple as possible as you can.

```
public class UserModel {
    public string Username { get set }
}
```

in the controller you take care of populating the model

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    model = new UserModel { Username = Session["someSession"] == null ? "" : Session["someSession"].ToString() }

return View(model);
}
```

In your view I would not combine razor and Javascript like that. You can assign values to JavaScript variables from a model

so, in JavaScript you could do something like this:

```
var username = '@Model.Username';
```

now you can continue with your js code and check if you have a value or not.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, would you please give me an example? Thanks

Comment: Thank you. But I have a question, do you think it is practical to create a class model just for this?

Comment: I am not able to use the @model.Username  inside my javascript code. The error message is: `The name does not exist in the current context`